# Generically calculate powers of two below a number

Tags: rust

The following function is an attempt to generate powers of two below the input number `max`.

So `powers_of_two_below(15u8, u8::BITS)` generates 1, 2, 4, 8. It does calculate 16, but does not include it. This function avoids calculating powers that cause overflow by taking `bits` as input (since there doesn't appear to be a standard trait that exposes `T::BITS`). It can be re-used for several number types.

But it doesn't seem very concise. Can you recommend ways to improve it?

```rust
use num_traits::{One, Zero};
use std::ops::Shl;

pub fn powers_of_two_below<T>(max: T, bits: u32) -> impl Iterator<Item = T>
where
    T: Zero + One + PartialOrd + Shl<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    let mut exp = T::zero();
    (0..bits)
        .map(move |_| {
            let power = T::one() << exp;
            exp = exp + T::one();
            power
        })
        .take_while(move |&x| x < max)
}
```

---

I tried to make a more concise version:

```rust
pub fn powers_of_two_below<T>(max: T, bits: u32) -> impl Iterator<Item = T>
where
    T: One + PartialOrd + Shl<Output = T> + Copy + From<u32>,
{
    (0..bits)
        .map(|i| T::one() << i.into())
        .take_while(move |&x| x < max)
}
```

...but it is more impractical: A lot of number types don't have `From<u32>` (including `usize` and *`uN`* where *`N`* < 32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the right hand side of `Shl`, you can remove the `From<u32>` entirely:

```rust
fn powers_of_two_below<T>(max: T, bits: u32) -> impl Iterator<Item = T>
where
    T: One + PartialOrd + Shl<u32, Output = T> + Copy,
{
    (0..bits)
        .map(|i: u32| T::one() << i)
        .take_while(move |&x| x < max)
}
```

If you wanted to remove the `bits` parameter, you'd probably have to implement your own trait specifically for it, but I'm not sure how you'd define `bits` for floating point numbers.

Here's an example where I defined a `Bits` trait, using a macro to implement it for all integer types. I also used it to replace `num_traits::One` because why not.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd4e4e7db8deb4c8be883c759dd906bf